# Global Source File Exclusions

Tags: sonarqube

I am using sonarqube 6.7

On Administration > Configuration > Analaysis Scope there are Global Source File Exclusions and Source File Exclusions. The description for Global Source File Exclusions is "Patterns used to exclude some source files from analysis. They apply to every project and cannot be overridden." while for Source File Exclusions is "Patterns used to exclude some source files from analysis."

What is the difference? I test it with "src/main/java/Exercise/Test*.java", and both exlude every project Test.java file.

Thank you.

Comment: Which part of the description is not clear?

Comment: They apply to every project and cannot be overridden. I try to test it and both apply to every project. And about cannot be overidden, I don't understand what is the meaning. I thought maybe if the file is read-only, but it still apply for both. So what I want to know, what is the difference between them. Thanks.

Comment: Is the difference that "Source File Exclusions" is overridable? I'm wondering about this, too.